# Bash script, combining directory size for all users in the system

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Okay, so basically right now I have a directory which is meant to collect files.

However, I need to find the total usage of the directory for all users in the system and it should be in bytes.

I am stuck on this for a long time and I would appreciate it if someone can help me a bit.

Comment: You mean the size of disk spaced used?

Comment: Please read this [Help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Comment: Which part of the problem are you stuck on exactly?

Comment: Yes, the size of disk space used.

Comment: I am stuck on the actual part of going through all users, getting the directory size and combining it with the others.

Comment: It looks like you made no effort at all: [linux user home directory size](https://www.google.com/search?q=linux+user+home+directory+size)

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking for the user home folders, then have a try with that:

```
du -b /home
```

Considering what exactly you mean by "users in system" you'd need to add the size of the `/root` folder, though that should only be a few bytes.

To find out about such utilities take a look at the `apropos` command on unixoid systems, here a `apropos disk space` reveals among many other things:

> du (1)               - estimate file space usage

As a next step the utilities manual page explains its usage and options:

```
man du
```

If the `/home` folder is *not* what you are interested in then you can implement a simple script iterating over all home folders as found in the `/etc/passwd` file and sum those values up.